# How to Data Loader delete records using external ids

Tags: data-loader, import-id

I want to delete some records from a custom object using import id. Is it possible using data loader, because when I try to delete the record using data loader I am only able to see id. I want to delete records using import id filed for maping, is it possible if yes please guide me how to do. Else guide me the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If by import id you mean an external id, that is not supported, you must use the Salesforce Id to delete the records via data loader. There is an idea out there to support this [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqjrAAC), which suggests a workaround:

> The workaround is pretty ugly. To each object, you add a "deleted"
>   field. You upsert records to be deleted with this field set as true.
>   You extract the them back with a salesforce id using extract in Data
>   Loader. You then delete them...